# How to: jQuery do something, when all vars are true?

Tags: jquery, variables, triggers, bind, each

I got problems to solve the following jQuery "issue":

The following code exits four times. When `var blk_img1_ready, var blk_imgX_ready` are `1/true` I would like to perform a function. But only if they are `true` together. The time, when it's done remains unknown.

(I searched for `trigger()` and `bind()` but didn't really understand, because there's no official event/trigger)

```
var elems1 = $('#balken1 .blk_img').find('*'), count1 = elems1.length;

elems1.each( function(i) {

    blk_img1++;
    $(this).attr('id','blk1-'+blk_img1);
    if(blk_img1==1)
    {
        $(this).css('display','block');
    }

    if (!--count1) blk_img1_ready=1;
});
```

Hope someone can help me through.
Thank you!

Comment: Just a few questions so I can help you, what exactly are you checking for? Do you mean you want to fire an event once the `.each()` function has finished?

Comment: @Joe 
Exactly. I want to fire an event, if all (4 .each() ) are ready

Comment: The code shown in your `.each()` loop is all _synchronous,_ which means that whatever code you put after it will not run until the `.each()` is finished. So if you simply put the four loops one after the other you can call your other function immediately after the fourth loop. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Joe
 Hoped there could be something else, than fire an event in an interval, and reset the interval if all vars are true.

Comment: Yes, you can use `setInterval()` to monitor the values of the variables, but you don't need to because you haven't shown any async code. How is the code you've shown with the `.each()` loop called?

Comment: @nnnnnn I'll give it a try. But I thought they are asynchronous and running something like the "same" time.

Comment: Are you doing something else not shown in your question? The code you've shown is definitely synchronous. (Also, ignoring web-workers, JS doesn't ever run code more than one piece of code at the same time.)

Comment: The above code is called in a javascript function on `$(document).ready()`

Comment: OK. Then please try just putting your four loops one after the other and then calling the other function you want to do when all are finished. It'll work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
var elements = $('#balken1 .blk_img').find('*');

elements.each( function(i) {
    $(this).attr('id','blk1-'+i).css('display','block');
});

// run your other code here
```

To just set the first element to `display:block` use:

```
elements.each( function(i) {
    $(this).attr('id','blk1-'+i);
}).first().css('display','block');
```

Comment: But the `.each()` shown will definitely be finished before that `.promise()` statement is even reached, so doesn't that make it redundant?

Comment: OK. By the way, nice job showing how to reduce the OP's `.each()` to one line.

Comment: I'll check it now. (You would hate me for posting the hole code ^^). Yes, you could reduce it to one line in that way, but only, if you want to set all elements to display as `block` not only the first.

Comment: ok so far :D ... Why I asked for this after all `each()` I tried to use something like `$('#blk1-1').css('height','1000px')` but the element doesn't react in any kind. So I thought they weren't complete, or wren't ready in DOM.

Comment: They are `img`. In next steps I want to start a small slideshow. The images are called from ajax (php file) and are set via `append` to the parent div

Comment: Are you trying to loop through the `imgs`? Are they inside an element called `.blk_img`?

Comment: Yes they are inside the element `.blk_img` but they aren't there when HTML loads. After `$(document).ready()`, I call an `$.ajax()` synchronous with `get` and append them `onsuccess` to the right element (`#balken1 .blk_img` to `#balken4 .blk_img`)

Comment: If you use the code straight after the `append` function (in the `onsuccess` callback) and do `$('#balken1 .blk_img').find('img')` then it should work fine.